# xdotool not working over AWS ubuntu instance

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, gnome, display, xdotool

I am working on bash script to automate w3m browser using xdotool I hosted this script in aws ubuntu instance but when i am executing this script i am getting below error

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
No protocol specified
```

below is the script

```
    #!/bin/sh
filename="links"
while read line; do
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/ubuntu/.Xauthority
"w3m $line"
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Return
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Return
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Tab
xdotool key Return
xdotool key Return
sleep 30m
done < $filename
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `xdotool` is a "command-line **X11** automation tool".  That's the very first line of the man page.   It requires X.
2. your AWS Ubuntu instance is probably not running X.   While you can install it, it's not something that's usually installed or used on an AWS instance.
3. `w3m` is a text-based web browser.  While it can run in an X terminal emulator, X is not required, and no X features are used.

To automate text-based command line programs, use [expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/) or one of the expect-like libraries for programming languages.  For example, perl's [Expect.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RGIERSIG/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) or python's [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect).

Comment: is there any way to make this script work with xdotool

Comment: Not with xdotool, use expect.  And not with your script as written - even if you moved the double-quotes from before `"w3m`  to before `$line"` so that it actually ran, the xdotool commands wouldn't even run until after w3m has exited.  There's too much wrong with your script.  Start over from scratch, and use the right tool for the job, expect or one of the expect-like libs.